# what is a #define _WIN32_DCOM a in visual c++ project?

Tags: c++, com, activex, dcom

What is

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
```

in a visual c++ project ? If I want to target the application build to x64, do I need to change it to WIN64_DCOM object ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368878(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Microsoft support:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158723)

> If your custom interface uses BSTR, VARIANT, or SAFEARRAY, and if you
>   want to use your custom interface marshaling code only on a DCOM
>   platform, you can use MIDL generated marshaling code. You will need to
>   use -D_WIN32_DCOM as a C compiler flag in the build process of the
>   MIDL generated code. Otherwise, a compiler error will be generated
>   that indicates that your code will compile only if you mark it as
>   runable only on a DCOM platform.

The symbol is a logic ones, you may use it unchanged under Windows 64 bits